# sum polylogarith convergence

Tags: summation

I am working in the following series i get a result could you help to see the convergence any ideas
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \text{Li}_k(-a)}{a}=\frac{a-\log (a+1)}{a^2}$$
where Lk is the polylogaritm.

Comment: Have you tried writing the polylogarithm as an integral, and then switching the order of summation and integration?

Comment: Yes lucian you are wright but o do not show the convergence of the serie